# rpsls game "(python) error:cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects

Tags: python

```
def name_to_number(name):
if name == "rock":
    number = 0
elif name == "Spock":
    number = 1
elif name == "paper":
    number = 2  
elif name == "lizard":
    number = 3
else :
    number = 4
return number
def number_to_name(number):
    if number == 0:
        name = "rock"
    elif number == 1:
        name = "Spock"
    elif number == 2:
        name = "paper"
    elif number == 3:
        name = "lizard"
    else:
        name = "scissors"
    return name

import random
def rpsls(player_choice):
    print ""
    print " Player chooses " + player_choice
    player_number = name_to_number(player_choice)
    comp_number = random.randrange(0, 5)
    comp_choice = name_to_number(comp_number)
    **print " Computer chooses " + comp_choice**
    difference = (player_number - comp_choice) % 5
    if difference == 1 or difference == 2:
        print "Player wins!"
    elif difference == 3 or difference == 4:
        print "Computer wins!"
    else:
        print "Player and Computer tie!"
        print ""

rpsls("rock")
rpsls("Spock")
rpsls("paper")
rpsls("lizard")
rpsls("scissors")
```

===============================================================

The problem is line 32, print "Computer chooses " + comp_choice
I've been wondering what's wrong with it?
Can somebody help please? (I've used ** to highlight the part containing the error.)

Comment: One line before that, you should be calling `number_to_name` __not__ `name_to_number` as you're passing a number to it. Also, one line after that, you should be subtracting `comp_number` from `player_number` __not__ `comp_choice` as it will be a string if you fix the first error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace line 31 with

```
comp_choice = number_to_name(comp_number)
```

Previously it was `name_to_number` which always returns number. And thus you were getting an error when adding it to the string.